# Bootstrap: Navbar items links are moving on mobile view toggle navbar when hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hover, cross-platform

I'm working on a project and I'm having this problem that when the menus are viewed on mobile device and you try to hover your mouse, it's moving the other menus and moving the `navbar` size.

```css
a.nav-link{
        letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
        color: green !important;
        border: 0.1rem solid transparent;
    }
    
    a.nav-active, a.nav-link:hover{
        border: 0.1rem solid #fff;
        color: #fff !important;
        transition: all 0.009s ease;
    }
    
    .navbar-toggler:focus,
    .navbar-toggler:active,
    .navbar-toggler-icon:focus {
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid pr-0 pl-0">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BLANK</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
               <span class="nav-icon-color" role="button" ><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#e6e6ff"></i></span>
            </button>
    
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link mr-4 nav-active" href="#">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link mr-4" href="#">SERVICES</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link mr-4" href="#">ABOUT</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link mr-4" href="#">CONTACT</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link mr-4" href="#">LOCATION</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u6dqhts0/1/

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: I don't see a menu when viewing on a small screen (lower than the Bootstrap L setting).

Comment: Updated the fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mk5thvdz/2/) I noticed the *content size* of the `<li> items` is indeed changing during hover.

The reason is because in your code you set the border to none, so the effective *content size* required by that item is all of a sudden lowered when hovering over it, and raised again when moving the mouse cursor away.

The following code needs to be inserted/updated in your CSS for it to work properly (code is used in update Fiddle, but not shown in post).

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 990px) {
    a.nav-link {
        border: 0.1rem solid transparent;
    }

    a.nav-active, a.nav-link:hover{
        border: 0.1rem solid transparent;
        color:#fff !important;
        transition: all 0.007s ease;
    }
}
```

The real solution is in the setting of the border to transparent during the hover, that was really all what was needed.

Example in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jcoLkr3d/).